# Writing proofs to show that a set is open, not closed and infinite

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, supremum-and-infimum

I have this problem with my homework

6. Let $E$ be a non-empty bounded set of real numbers and put $\alpha = \sup E ,$
   and $\beta = \inf E$ . Assume that $\alpha \notin E$ and $\beta \notin E .$ Which of the following statements
   is true and which is false. In each case justify your answer.

(a) $E$ is an open set.

(b) $E$ is not a closed set.

(c) $E$ is an infinite set.

(d) $( \alpha , \beta ) \subset E$

It's about general topology and inf and sup. We have to state whether each statement is true or false and justify by giving nice proofs. My assumptions are:
1)False
2)True
3)True
4)False

Please, I need help in writing appropriate proofs. I'm new to this course and still don't know how to write proofs. Any help is appreciated. I only have problems proving part d), if anyone can help me. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @YuiTo Cheng: Transcribing an image into text is good; transcribing it into $\rm\LaTeX$, not as good.

Answer (score 0):

You should do your homework yourself. 
But you are right about your decision which is true and false.

If the statement is false, you can give just a simple counterexample.

**Hints:**

b) Assume $E$ is closed. The limit of each convergent sequence in E is in E. Now, use the property of either infimum or supremum to get a contradition.

c) Assume $E$ is finite. What is the supremum and infimum of a finite set?

Comment: Thanks for the advice! concerning part c, if E is finite then the set E must contain its supremum and infimum, right? but in my case, I'm given that they do not belong to E. Is this a nice counter example?

Comment: Yes, that argument is correct and sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The convention is to show that a statement is false by providing a counter-example and to show that it's true by giving a general proof.

$(a)$ Consider the counter-example $E=(0,1]\cup[2,3).\alpha=3,\beta=0$ but $E$ is not open.

$(b)$ A closed set contains all its limit points. Show that $\alpha$ is a limit point of $E$ by noting that $N_\epsilon(\alpha)\cap E-\{\alpha\}\ne\phi$. Since $\alpha\notin E,E$ is not closed.

$(c)$ If $E$ were to be finite, it would be closed. We have just shown that $E$ is not closed.

$(d)$ The same counter-example as in $(a)$ works here too.

Comment: Thank you so much, you helped me a lot! Though how did you know that Nϵ(α)∩E−{α}≠ϕ ? Can you please explain this to me.

Comment: @souadbouchahine It was meant to be a clue for you to build on. Anywho, you just have to use the basic properties of supremum. Since $\alpha-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound of $E,\exists x\in E|\alpha>x>\alpha-\epsilon$. Thus, $x$ lies in the intersection of $E$ and deleted neighbourhood of $\alpha$.

Comment: Okay, thank you for making this clear!

Comment: But how can the counter example of part a) work in part c) too? if α = 3 and β=0  then (α, β) = (3,0). Is that possible?

Comment: @souadbouchahine For the last option to make sense, it should be $(\beta,\alpha)$, not the other way round.

Comment: yes, this is what I meant. It doesn't make sense to use the same counter example as in part a). How can we give a counter example for part d) then?

Comment: Since $\beta\le\alpha,(\alpha,\beta)=\phi$. If you look at it this way, the empty set is a proper subset of every non-empty $E$, so there is no counter-example and the statement is true.

Comment: @souadbouchahine  What I was implying was that $(\alpha,\beta)$ is probably a typo in the question; it should have been the other way round. If not, the statement is true.

Comment: okay, I'll check with my professor if he made a typo. If this is the case then the statement is true?

Comment: Yes, If it's not a typo, $(\alpha,\beta)=\phi\subset E\ne\phi$

Comment: and if this is the case, then (α,β)⊂E in part d) is true?

Comment: @souadbouchahine Yes